# How to capture everything that user types in Android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

I want to write an android service (a background task) that captures everything that user types.

For example when the user types "Hello" in a text message (SMS), my service plays "Hello" from speakers, or when the user types "I love you" in an IM, my service plays a "KISS" sound effect.

How to capture everything that user types in Android?

It is not a keylogger, it is a fun app idea!

Comment: Technically it *is* a a keylogger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to write an android service (a background task) that captures everything that user types.

Fortunately, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. You are welcome to make your own ROM mod that has this security flaw.

> It is not a keylogger

[Yes, it is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keylogger)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it as background service.

However, you can implement your own inputmethod (software keyboard). But the user has to switch his inputmethod to this new keyboard. You can't do it w/o users consent.